# css media query don' t work after a css change made by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why `media query` don't work after I change the *width* of an HTML element with *javascript* . If for example an element has INITIALLY a width equal to `200px` and then I change its width to `100px` programmatically with *javascript* .So when I expect another  change of this width due to *media query* , it does not work , in fact it keeps the last size made by javascript as illustrated below .
**So can you explain to me why and can tackle this issue ?**

```
// Embedded CSS : initial width 
 #main { width:48%} 

let main = document.getElementById("main"); // html element
main.style.width="48%";

// css media query code which does not work due to javascript change
@media(max-width: 550px) {
  #main { width:100%}
}
```

**NB: IF NO CHANGE IS MADE BY JAVASCRIPT EVERYTHING IS OK**

Comment: First you have to add your code in question to get more help .... but in general  JavaScript will add inline styling which is stronger than external styling made by the media query try to use `!important ` inside your media query code

Comment: @IbramReda ok  added  some illustration for you .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try `!import` in your media query
... the width will be **100%** even if you try to change it by JavaScript it will be 100% for screen less than **550px**

### full working example

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const main = document.getElementById("main"); 
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  main.style.width="60%";
})
```

```css
#main{
  height:20px;
  width:48%;
  background-color:#00f;
  margin:auto;
}


@media(max-width: 550px) {
  #main { width:100% !important}
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<button id="btn">set style to 60% by js</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What javascript syntax did you use? If you use this syntax for example

```
document.getElementById("elem").style.width = "500px";
```

then it'll returns to an element's attribute not its css style

```
<div id="elem" style="width: 500px">Hello World!</div>
```

Fyi, media query only works if there're no any style added on inline-style, except if you add **!important** query on your css.